# In the US Civil War, what factors contributed to the Union having such a numerical advantage over the Confederacy?

Tags: american-civil-war

For example, why opposing slavery is more appealing than perpetuating it? I am looking for a historical pragmatic answer rather than a "moral" answer. Or why bother uniting? Why more states and their people (if it's democracy at that time) choose or vote to fight for the union/anti slavery/"north" side.

In the U.S. Civil War, the Union ihitially enjoyed a preponderance of states, 22 to 11, over the Confederacy, with a 5 to 2 manpower advantage, and a 9 to 1 advantage in industrial output.

Some of the "Union" states (Maryland, Delaware, Kentucky, and Missouri) were actually "Southern" slave states mostly south of the Mason-Dixon line. And two more states in similar latitudes, "bleeding Kansas" and West Virginia (which seceded from Confederate Virginia) joined the Union after the beginning of 1861, making the tally 24 (Union) to 11 (Confederate).

Why did the Union enjoy such a preponderance of states incluidng the six "border" states. Is there any informed opinion that suggests that one or more of the border states would have made a diifference if they had gone with the South?

Comment: This question could be answered with trivial research from wikipedia. (Check the table under "results and costs") https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Civil_war

Comment: An answer can be found here with the answer to this question:http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7715/what-did-sectionalism-have-to-do-with-the-american-civil-war?rq=1 In essence, the issue is Why did more states choose to side with the North than with the South?

Comment: You know what? I am quite annoyed with this closed as not a real question. What is so not real in this question? At least we need a much more clear close option.

Comment: I have read that wikipedia. It's not clear from there.

Comment: @Tom Au - My concern now is that the change has made the question one that is more likely to be answered subjectively. The only way I can see it being answered is with specualtion, rather than facts. It's almost like saying "If the south had tanks and bazookas, could they have won?" I'm osrry, but I still don't see it as a good fit.

Comment: @JimThio: I have tried to upgrade your question to get it reopened. I have one more upgrade in mind that I think will "do the job." Before I use it, do you agree with the direction I'm going? Or is it too far from your original questsion? Feel free to roll back the question to the original version if you don't like my "fixes."

Comment: I am just grateful. I am not american. Hence I don't know things american take it for granted.

Comment: Also I am more of interested in the number advantage. Why more people opposes slavery than those wanting to perpetuate it. That's eventually something I want to learn. Can't be morality. C'mon.... Different wage? Cotton? Different industry? What?

Comment: Mr. Thio, that question "Why did more people fight to oppose slavery than fight to preserve it?" is much better than the one above.  It still asks us to interpret behavior, and confuses "fighting to oppose slavery" with "fighting to preserve the union", but I think if you ask that question rather than this one, you'll be much closer to an answer.

Comment: Good work adding "meat" to the question. An upvote from me.

Comment: Yea.... That would be like it. What's so appealing about a certain political causes that many want to promote it.

Comment: I had family in the south and the north.  Almost all of my ancestors and their near relatives born from 1840 to 1848 served in the Civil War.  Of my northern ancestors, barely any had to serve.  The North just had more people than it needed, really, and the South had every capable fighter fight because it was an existential battle from their point of view.

Comment: Interesting to call the South's compulsory conscription law, and the changing of all terms of service to 'forever' during the war, an *"existential battle"*.  Many if not most southern soldiers fought because they were forced to, and desertion rates were quite high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the North's population outnumber the South, or merely have more men available to be conscripted into the army to fight?

The answer to this question is less about industrialisation and more about the *availability* of qualified men able to be conscripted into the army to fight.

The southern states had a totally different economy to the north and was based primarily on slave labour. This slave labour, consisting mostly of African-American (is that the correct term?) descent were not available to join the army and fight. It's true the confederate Army did enlist some slaves towards the end of the war, but at the beginning the Confederate Army consisted mostly of non-slaves.

This is the reason for the larger Union Armies compared to the Confederate ones.

Comment: Hm, this doesn't sound right, the Union's soldiers represented 10% of its total population in 1860 while the Confederacy soldiers represented 11.7% of its total population in 1860. It seems that the Confederacy managed to conscript relatively more men than the Union, even though in absolute numbers the Union army was double the size.

Comment: What do those figures represent and where are you getting them from? Were slaves counted in 'total population'? Bear in mind that the slave population of the south was quite large and as I've said, slaves were not eligible for conscription. Also bear in mind that ex-slaves (freed slaves) _were_ eligible to join the Union Army.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Civil_war#Results_and_costs - and, yes slaves were counted in the figures for total population.

Comment: Well the answer's there - read the difference in figures for free v slave for both the Union and The Confederacy. 89% of the South's population were slaves who were not eligible to join the Army compared with 11% of the Union who were slaves (who wern't eligible). That left just 19% of the free Southern population consisting of men women and children. What are you disagreeing with?

Comment: Again: Relatively to their population, the Confederacy managed to conscript _more_ soldiers. If they had a population equal to the Union, they would have a bigger army than the Union did (even if they only draw that army from the 19% of their population). To me it seems that the vast difference in population is the key factor that the Union had a bigger army, and not really what you're saying (certainly also a factor, but not as important as you're assuming perhaps). That said, I blame the vagueness of the question, no point in us arguing over a sub par question, voting to close.

Comment: Relative to their population the Confederacy _had_ to conscript more solidiers! If you don't think that 89% of the Souths population consisting of slaves who were not eligible to join the Army had a negative impact on the numbers of soldiers they could recruit, that is of course your prerogative. As far as I'm concerned (and according to the masses of literature I've read on the subject) that was the principle reason for the disparity in Soldier numbers and is the correct answer to the question asked.

Comment: References to the masses of literature would be more than helpful ;)

Comment: No I don't think it would be to be honest. The answer is so blatantly obvious (and the figures more than support it) that it's not worth continuing to discuss. Just accept some of us rely on knowledge gained from books and not constantly trawling Wikipedia articles.

Comment: Hm, you know you can reference those books right? Also what might be blatantly obvious to you doesn't necessarily have to be blatantly obvious to _everyone_, by answering a question I'm assuming you _want_ to help people by sharing your knowledge in a way most of them will understand, not just state the bloody obvious.

Comment: How do you expect me to reference dozens of books read many years ago? I read several books a _week_ on a variety of different subjects. I posted that answer with no research and before reading that wikipedia article, yet the figures support it. The Confederacy had 1/2 the population of the North and of that 89% of that population were slaves. Why are you surprised that the Confederacy not only had a much smaller army, but also had to conscript far more of their eligible population? Isn't it obvious to you?

Comment: Guys, take a break.  Then delete **all** your comments and write one, and only one, that state your point in an assertive manner with the aim of **improving the answer**.  This is getting a little like a flame war. ^_~

Answer (score 2):

There were more people living in the North mostly due to better climate, migrations, and urbanisation -- see [the 1860 census](http://archive.org/stream/populationofusin00kennrich#page/n13/mode/2up) or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Civil_war#Results_and_costs).  It was much more industrialised than the South. [Bruce Catton](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bruce-Catton/e/B000AP8M9Q/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1) and [Shelby Foote](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Shelby-Foote/e/B000AQ48MU/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1) are good sources if you wanted to learn more about the American civil war.

Comment: So it's not really north vs south. It's the whole US vs some small number of southern regions.

Comment: No, it is North vs South states. If you are genuinely interested, pick a book by either Catton or Foote. They have written some good introduction texts detailing the war.

Comment: Summarizing it as "whole US vs some small number of southern regions" misrepresents the problem.  From the foundation of the republic there were serious differences between northern and southern states. (I'm not sure why you use the term "regions".)

Comment: This answer is a really poor one, there's no reasoning at all behind the answer. Yes, the North was more industrialised, but why would this represent a larger number of fighting men than the south?

Comment: @Sardathrion - No, Jim Thio's correct. Arkansas had units in both the Union and Confederate armies,  Mississippi had an entire county secede to rejoin the Union, Maryland and Kentucky were geographically, culturally and economically southern, and declared for Union, and California is on the same latitude as most of the south.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: reference added.

Comment: @RISwampYankee: Any generalisation about the US Civil War are wrong. ^_~

Comment: There were plenty of Unionists living in the hill country in Tennesee.  North Carolina, and Alabama.  There were secessionists living in the upper quarter of Missouri along the Missouri river.

Answer (score 2):

The preponderance of 22 (later 24) Union states over the 11 Confederate states made things very difficult for the latter. Even so, it was a fairly close issue, and the Union needed every advantage. If a few more states had actually sided with the Confederacy, the outcome might have gone the other way.

President Lincoln famously said, "I hope to have God on my side, but I must have Kentucky...To lose Kentucky is almost to lose the whole game." http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/05/07/bluegrass-blues-and-grays/

Regarding the German-Amerioans who "held the fort" for the Union in Missouri, Grant said, "Recapturing St. Louis would have been a terrible job a most difficult task to give to any military man. Instead of a campaign before Vicksburg, it would have been a campaign before St. Louis." (Joseph Wandels, "The German Dimension in American History.")

As to why the Union enjoyed such a preponderance, one explanation can be found in my answer to this question. [What did sectionalism have to do with the American civil war?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7715/what-did-sectionalism-have-to-do-with-the-american-civil-war)

Also, I've noticed that "cold" parts of the country (compared to Richmond, Virginia), tended to be pro Union (including mountainous regions in Southern latitudes), while "hot" regions (again compared to Richmond), tended to be pro Confederacy, with the notable exception of California. To test this theory, I asked this question. [What are exceptions to the hypothesis that "climate determined "regional" loyalties in the U.S. Civil War"?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8309/what-are-exceptions-to-the-hypothesis-that-climate-determined-regional-loyalty)

Basically, there were a bunch of "mini civil wars in Border States like Kentucky and Missouri, which went in favor of the Union. (And I'd include latecomers Kansas and West Virginia in the mix; the exception was Tennessee, where West and Middle Tennessee "outvoted" East Tennessee and kept that state in the Confederacy.) Then the border states joined the nothern states in crushing the South.

Comment: The slaveholding area in Missouri was in the north, a belt East of Kansas City.

Comment: @Oldcat: From what I understand, northern Missouri has more "lowlands," and is therefore the most "temperate" part of the state, especially given the presence of the Missouri River. Meanwhile southern Missouri has more (and colder) "highlands." So the relationship may hold true in a roundabout way. That is, northern Missouri is about as warm as Richmond, VA (on the same latitude), while southern Missouri is "colder."

Comment: The weather is not different along the Missouri River than in other parts of the state.  There is just more flatland for intensive farming and easy transportation by river, so it was developed more intensively.  The most Union oriented area of Missouri, the St. Louis area, is also in the "lowlands".  So is the entire Ohio River valley.  I've lived there, the same weather moves from west to east during the year.